# How can I parse this json schema in Objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an iOS app that seek station , and I would like add the Fuel price.

I found an Opendata with the database, but I can't parse the array "Fields" and "price_e10", only the array "Records".

Here's an example of JSON SCHEMA (I think it's multidimensional-array):

```
"records":[
{
"datasetid":"prix_des_carburants_j_7",
"recordid":"fa74ca1fdf6938333d2bc1013623b66771557b31",
"fields":{
"price_e10":1.389,
```

Here the example of my code in Objective-c :

```
NSError *e;
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    NSArray *arrayResult =[dict objectForKey:@"records"];
    arraySmpl = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayResult];

    NSLog(@" MULTIPLE ARRAY : %@ ",arrayResult);
    rowsInSection = [arraySmpl count] + 1;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `arrayResult` is a NSArray of NSDictionary. For key `fields`, the value is a `NSDictionary`. => `NSString *aprice = [[arrayResult objectAtIndex:??] objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"price_e10]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I considered **data** is coming from server.

```
NSDictionary *globalDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
NSArray *recordsArray = [globalDict valueForKey:@"records"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in recordsArray) {
    NSDictionary *fieldsDict = [dict valueForKey:@"fields"];
    NSString *fuelPrice = [fieldsDict valueForKey:@"price_e10"];
    NSLog(@"fuelPrice: %@", fuelPrice);
}
```

**Output :** fuelPrice: 1.389

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

```
 NSArray *rec = [allDict objectForKey:@"records"];  
     for (NSDictionary *str in loans) {
     NSDictionary *conn = [str objectForKey:@"fields"];
            NSStirng *get_price = [conn objectForKey:@"price_e10"];
    }
```

now the String "get_price" will have the value of 1.389,

Comment: Thanks for your help , i need your help for display the price of GAZOLE , PRICE-E10  .... in an table view

Answer (score 0):

Like i above mentioned for "Price_e10", you can directly access price_gazole price_sp95 , price_sp98.

```
NSArray *rec = [allDict objectForKey:@"records"];  
         for (NSDictionary *str in loans) {
         NSDictionary *conn = [str objectForKey:@"fields"];
                NSStirng *get_price = [conn objectForKey:@"price_e10"];
 NSStirng *price_gazole = [conn objectForKey:@"price_gazole"]; //output: 1.205
 NSStirng *price_sp95 = [conn objectForKey:@"price_sp95"];  //output :1.425

 NSStirng *price_sp98 = [conn objectForKey:@"price_sp98"]; //output 1.465

        }
```

Comment: ok thanks , how add this to an array for display in my TableView ?